# Shrink tab size when pinned in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

is there a way to shrink tab size when pinned in IntelliJ can the ide be be modified to do so

I would like my pinned db tab to be smaller than the working tabs

Comment: could u provide more details with image?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not yet. Here's a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123086